# Evaluation order and optimization for Joins and Unions

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I need to execute dynamically formed querys.

This querys will be brought together by set operations inner join (acting as and AND) and union (acting as an OR) to obtain one result set.

Let's say the user inputs: A & B | C & D

where

- A = 'select num from table_a'
- B = 'select num_b from table_b'
- C = 'select num_c from table_c'
- D = 'select num_d from table_d'

To get one result set I'll execute dynamically:

```
select * from A inner join B union C inner join D;
```

I know how the optimizer works with joins an unions separately but I couldn't find any information on how are they evaluated together.

Given that the input could be interpreted as:

- (A & B) | (C & D)
- A & (B | C) & D
- A & (B | (C & D))
- (A & B | C) & D

My questions are:

**How will the optimizer execute this set operations?**

**Are the parentheses relevant in this case?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Would the neg voter care to explain whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
select * from A inner join B union 
select * from C inner join D;
```

This is effectively:

```
(select * from A inner join B) union 
(select * from C inner join D);
```

Edit:

Actually, it would probably be better to express your logic as:

```
select * from A
intersect
select * from B
union 
select * from C
intersect
select * from D;
```

... which is effectively:

```
(((select * from A
intersect
select * from B)
union 
select * from C)
intersect
select * from D);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm

In case of any doubt, always specify parentheses yourself.

Comment: Hi David, the parentheses were omitted to avoid another grade of complexity to the user. But other than that, I see where I was mistaken.